# Reading and returning file lines

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to create a program to open and read a file, printing each line. What I have seems to match up with what I've seen elsewhere, yet the program does not print after opening. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    std::ifstream myfile("path\\M321words.txt");
    myfile.open("M321words.txt");
    std::string myline;
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (myfile) { // equivalent to myfile.good()
            std::getline(myfile, myline);
            std::cout << myline << '\n';
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Couldn't open file\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You try to open two different files: `path\M321words.txt` and `M321words.txt`. Which one is correct?

Comment: OT: Change: `while (myfile) { // equivalent to myfile.good()
            std::getline(myfile, myline);` to  `while (std::getline(myfile, myline) {`

Comment: by the way, the comment "equivalent to myfile.good()" is wrong: it's equivalent to `!myfile.fail()`, which is very different, because reaching the end of a file is not a fail. And that is a problem in your program!

Comment: Side note: Opening a file in a file stream that's already open places the stream into failure mode and makes it unreadable until the mistake is acknowledged and `clear`ed. [Highlander's law applies here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcLjcSloXs).

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the file twice, and in two different locations. Either

```
std::ifstream myfile("path\\M321words.txt");
```

or

```
std::ifstream myfile("M321words.txt");
```

Of course neither may be correct, if the file name is not correct.

And the loop is incorrect, use the return value of `getline` to determine if it succeeded

```
while (std::getline(myfile, myline))
    std::cout << myline << '\n';
```

Comment: I have tried the edits mentioned but still have not gotten it to print sadly. open function has been omitted for just the ifstream, and loop changed from prior for-while to the above. Anything else you advise trying?

Comment: @Islandari If the code is correct then the most likely reason for the problem is that you are failing to open the file, and the most likely reason for that is that you are looking for the file in the wrong place. When you are dealing with file always check that they open successfully, the code in the answer below shows how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{        
    std::ifstream myfile("test.txt");
    std::string myline;
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        for (std::string line; std::getline(myfile, line); )
        {
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Couldn't open file\n";
    }
    myfile.close();
    return -1;
}
```

You while loop should be constructed like that:

```
while(!myfile.eof())  // EOF is false here
{
    std::getline(myfile, line);
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

You need to check for the end of the file.
That's why it didn't work.

Comment: Note that code-only answers are generally frowned upon. You should explain what is wrong with the OP's code, and explain how this code fixes the problem.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Use `while (std::getline(myfile, myline) {` instead of making use of eof which could cause an extra empty line being processed.

Comment: Even following this it can not open the file. Should I edit the question to show what I just tried? Could it have something to do with using VS in particular?

Comment: Maybe you named the file differently than you think. If you have the "hide file extensions for known types" option of the file explorer turned on you may have created `M321words.txt.txt` and not know it because your file browser hid that from you.

Comment: @Islandari check 'drescherjm' comment, the code in the 'example' should work, you just forgot the correct condition for the while loop. 'while (myfile)', myfile is a reference or address.