# How do i write into JSON files using C++ (nlohmann)?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

How do I write into a JSON file from C++?
I am using nlohmann's json.hpp and included it into my c++. I want to store some information like "name" "age" "tel" and "mail" in a json file that i can write into from my c++ programm.

I have know how to write into a JSON using `data["Infos"][0]["name"] = "Joe";` JSON before that:

```
{
    "Infos": [
        {
            "name": "Lukas",
            "age": "16",
            "tel": "1233321",
            "mail": "adsf@gmail.com"
        }

    ]
}
```

After running the code, the "name" gets changed to "Joe", but i have no clue how to add another guy to that json that it looks like that:

```
{
    "Infos": [
        {
            "name": "Lukas",
            "age": "16",
            "tel": "1233321",
            "mail": "adsf@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "New",
            "age": "50",
            "tel": "123456789",
            "mail: "newguy@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have code in my C++ that asks the user for the new guys name, age, tel and mail but i dont know how to add that information to my json file. Sorry for bad english or formating some stuff in ways that aren't easy understandable but i tried my best :D

If anyone has an idea of how this could be possible, or have questions yourself, I appreciate every answer/question to this post!

This is my first question so i didnt know that you have to write the things you tried seperately sorry, i listed everything i tried so far and what i was expecting in the details part of my question

Comment: Check out [the documentation](https://github.com/nlohmann/json?tab=readme-ov-file#json-as-first-class-data-type), it has a nearly identical example.

Comment: Please, take the [tour] and read [ask]. _I have code in my C++_ Which code? I cannot see the code on your computer... ;-)

Comment: check this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77943938/1825056 , it allows you to read a 'txt' file line by line and than you have to check all 'character' of each line and a split them accordingly, on 'Hackerrank' there is code challenge on how to read a HTML type of file and read it contents.